# Correcting a naive Bayes classifier based on the performance on the training dataset

Tags: probability, bayesian, classification, conditional-probability, naive-bayes

I'm sorry, this seems like something that's already been discussed to death, but I don't seem to be able to phrase the question right to find the answer.

Say I have a naive Bayes spam filter trained on a dataset which I then use as a test set, and find that my NBC correctly flags 90% of spam emails and 85% of ham emails. Should I not now apply Bayes' theorem to the results produced by my NBC, with .9 and .85 as priors? Could/should I do it with raw probabilities or Bayes factors?

I'm less interested in the improvement of accuracy, and more in getting the probabilities that are as close to the truth as possible.

Comment: I think the conventional wisdom is that Naive Bayes is a good classifier but gives poor probabilities (i.e. it is poorly calibrated).  Let me see if I can find a reference for this.

Comment: @DemetriPananos Thanks. This is an important piece of information, and I think "calibration" may be the key word that I needed to "phrase the question right".